# How to convert mixed datetime format records using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have pandas column like as shown below

```
23/6/2011 7:00     
21/4/1998 05:00       
17/02/1990  
11/01/1985 30:30:01       
26/02/1976 
45:42:7
```

You can see the column doesn't have any fixed format for the date column.

So, when I try to convert them to a datetime column, most of the records become `NaN`

I tried the below but both doesn't worl

```
df['test_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['test_date']) # it leads to long integer like 130825789000000000
df['test_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['test_date'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce') #this makes all other format records as NA
```

I expect my output to be like as below.  If the below output is not possible, I would at least like to have the `date values` as output

```
23/6/2011  07:00:00    
21/4/1998  05:00:00       
17/02/1990 00:00:00
11/01/1985 10:30:01       
26/02/1976 00:00:00
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce `df['test_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['test_date'])` parses the dates correctly with `00:00:00` time where's missing.

Comment: updated my sample data @AndrejKesely

Comment: How do you want to parse the time `30:30:01`?

Comment: I know it is invalid record. So, instead of making that record `NA`, I would like to retain it like `11/01/1985 00:00:00`.... If not possible, I would just like to retain the date values only for the whole column

Comment: see updated sample for another issue that I encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from dateutil import parser


def parse_dates(x):
    out = []
    for v in x:
        try:
            out.append(pd.to_datetime(v))
            continue
        except parser._parser.ParserError:
            v = v.split()[0]
            try:
                out.append(pd.to_datetime(v))
            except:
                out.append(pd.NaT)
    return out


df["test_date"] = parse_dates(df["test_date"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            test_date
0 2011-06-23 07:00:00
1 1998-04-21 05:00:00
2 1990-02-17 00:00:00
3 1985-11-01 00:00:00
4 1976-02-26 00:00:00
5                 NaT
```

---

`df` used:

```
             test_date
0       23/6/2011 7:00
1      21/4/1998 05:00
2           17/02/1990
3  11/01/1985 30:30:01
4           26/02/1976
5              45:42:7
```

Answer (score 1):

More simply:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['test_date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

0   2011-06-23 07:00:00
1   1998-04-21 05:00:00
2   1990-02-17 00:00:00
3   1985-11-01 10:30:01
4   1976-02-26 00:00:00
Name: test_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

**Old answer**

```
# from dateutil import parser
>>> df['test_date'].map(parser.parse)

0   2011-06-23 07:00:00
1   1998-04-21 05:00:00
2   1990-02-17 00:00:00
3   1985-11-01 10:30:01
4   1976-02-26 00:00:00
Name: test_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, let's say there is one invalid date value `32/05/1998 00:00:00`. would it just make it `NA`?

Comment: Because I get an error like this `ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 45:42.7`

Comment: when I try the below `pd.to_datetime(df['test_date'], infer_datetime_format=True,errors='ignore')`, I get an error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: For ex: If a record has value like `10/05/2011 45:02:07`, i would like to retain the date value instead of having `NaT` due to incorrect Hour value. Hence I was trying to retain `date` values for all my records. it's fine if we are not able to retain timestamp